# In transaction NACE, is it possible to find out the print program and form routine, if i know the name of the Smartform?

Tags: printing, document, abap, sap-smart-forms

I want to find out the name of the Print Program, and the name of the subroutine (form) that prints my SmartForm.

Now luckily in NACE (Conditions for Output Control), one can "kinna" figure out the application and the output type by oneself, and then the print program is obviously written there.

So what about if one wouldn't know what application and Output Type, and would have to check all applicatios and output types manually? isn't there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Is "invoking the debugger and checking the call stack" an option for you?

Comment: Yes. I did that in the meantime actually and i found my print program. You could post this as an answer so i can thumb you up :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table TNAPR contains some print program -> script links, search for your smartform name in field SFORM. This is by no means an exhaustive list, however.

OR

Do a "where used" search for "SSF_FUNCTION_MODULE_NAME", which will give you a list of all smartform calling programs. You'd still need to go through it manually, but you might find a suitably matching program description or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find out the actual printing program for a certain form **and** it is possible to get a print preview, you can always enter the debugger using `/h` and examine the call stack.

Comment: and when a popup gets in the way of being able to type in the /h then one can always create a SAPShortcut with the command /h and drag-n-drop it over the popup. Thx for  the tip, I was already aware of it.